# CNN+LSTM OCR model not predicting "is" correctly

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr, lstm, conv-neural-network

I have made a model in tensorflow with the following structure for OCR. I trained it on a significantly large dataset(250K images) and also getting around 94% accuracy. But the model predicts "is" as "1s" or "1S" most of the times. I checked the dataset and it contains quite a lot of instances of "is" so I dont think dataset is the problem. Also the model predicts correctly when it is a part of another word such as "this" or "christian". What could possibly be the reasons for this behaviour how can I improve the model to detect "is".

**Things I tried**

Decrease number of maxpool layers.

Use 2x1 kernels for maxpool layers

```
Input: (?, 64, 1024, 1)
cnn-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
relu-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
bn-1: [None, 64, 1024, 64]
maxpool-1: [None, 32, 512, 64]
cnn-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
relu-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
bn-2: [None, 32, 512, 128]
maxpool-2: [None, 16, 256, 128]
cnn-3-1: [None, 16, 256, 256]
relu-3-1: [None, 16, 256, 256]
cnn-3-1: [None, 16, 256, 256]
relu-3: [None, 16, 256, 256]
bn-3: [None, 16, 256, 256]
maxpool-3: [None, 8, 128, 256]
cnn-4-1: [None, 8, 128, 512]
relu-4-1: [None, 8, 128, 512]
bn-4-1: [None, 8, 128, 512]
cnn-4-2: [None, 8, 128, 512]
relu-4-2: [None, 8, 128, 512]
bn-4-2: [None, 8, 128, 512]
maxpool-4: [None, 4, 64, 512]
cnn-5: [None, 4, 64, 512]
relu-5: [None, 4, 64, 512]
lstm-input: [None, 64, 2048]
lstm-output: [None, 64, 256]
lstm-output-reshaped: [None, 256]
fully-connected: [None, 94]
reshaped_logits: [None, None, 94]
transposed_logits: [None, None, 94]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since probably most numbers in your dataset are preceded by spaces, and "1" and "i" look similar, it is somewhat of an understandable error.

I do not thing changing the architecture of the network will help at all.

What I would do is to artificially *oversample* the "is" instances. You say there are already many instances of it - but probably not enough. So with some probability of 5% - 10% force the text sample at a location that will contain an "is". You don't even need to restart the whole training, you can continue training an already trained network like this, and it will force the network to be biased towards "is".

If it now starts to misidentify "15" as "is" then with some smaller probability, like 2%-5%, add stretches that contain numbers like that as well. So like teaching a person, show it examples to allow it to learn the difference.

Don't raise the probabilities too high, though, because you will ruin the general accuracy. It will very quickly learn to tell *15* from *is* but will forget everything else...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a language model to correct spellings in ocr output. I think you can find one spell checker in nltk. More sophisticated spell checkers can be built using seq2seq autoencoders.